# How can I open a browser on a Collection of CompiledMethods in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I collected some CompiledMethods in an Array and now want to review them manually in a browser. Somehow i couldn’t find a solution in the Reflection Chapter of Pharo by Example.

What is the way to open a browser on a Collection of CompiledMethods in Pharo (1.4)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SystemNavigation default browseAllSelect: [ :e | methodCollection includes: e ].
```

Comment: Or: 
SystemNavigation default browseMessageList: (methodsCollection collect:#methodReference) name: 'My methods'

Btw, i am surprised that i unable to do just:

SystemNavigation default browseMessageList: methodsCollection name: 'My methods'

and need to convert methods to methodReference first